# What is the default typography for UINavigationBar in IOS 7?

Tags: ios, font, typography, font-sizes, apple

I know the font is either HelveticaNeue-Light or HelveticaNeue-Medium, but which is it? What is also the font size?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking us to identify a font.

Comment: Where do I go to identify a font, apple q&a cause it's not stackoverflow or is it another site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/the-ios-7-design-cheat-sheet/  -34 px HelveticaNeue-Medium.

answered yesterday by Mohsin